# How to add new attributes to Material UI Shadows | Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

[image]I am trying to customize the Material UI types for shadow, but getting the below error when I try to use it in my code.

```
Tuple type Shadows of length 25 has no element at index 25.
```

I have tried many solutions but none helped. Below is what I have tried:

I have a index.d.ts file defined at root level and adding the declare module to customize the shadow property of Mui theme.

```
declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/shadows' {
  type Shadows = [
    {
      a1: string;
      a2: string;
      a3: string;
    }
  ];
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. it does work for me.

Comment: @Mahdi - I have added the error screenshot, pls see if you can help

Comment: It says theme.shadows array has only 25 items, from index 0 to 24, so you should probably change it to theme.shadows[24]

Comment: @yaya - Default Mui Shadows ranges from [0-24], I am appending new one which is not detected by Mui Theme. URL for reference - https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/styles/shadows.d.ts

Comment: It seems it's typescript, so this touple has a type with 25 elements. Maybe you'll add new theme in realtime, but you didn't change the type to a touple with of size 26. So maybe you should somehow override the type and set it to a touple of length 26, or something similar.

Comment: @yaya - I tried other tuple solutions, but none worked, if possible could you please share solution? Thanks.

Comment: @user12133234 please reproduce the error with a minimal code on stackblitz, so then I can take a look on it.

Comment: @yaya - I will share the stackblitz example.

Comment: Did you find the solution? @user12133234

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can customize any of shadow using ES6 spread operator.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  shadows: [...createMuiTheme({}).shadows.map((shadow, i) => (
    i === 1 ? '0 0 18px 0 rgba(9, 32, 46, 0.2)' : shadow
  ))],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to add one additional customized shadow to your theme. I had a similar issue and solve the problem via the following codes:

The basic idea is that you need to put the original 25 shadows (index 0 - 24) in the "shadows" array, and then create an additional one after these 25 original shadows.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  shadows: [...createMuiTheme({}).shadows, "0px 4px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)"],
});
```

In this case the new shadow is added to the shadows array (with index 25).

Then you can apply this new shadow to your mui component via:

```
<Box sx={{boxShadow: "25"}}>
```

Same logic can be used to create 26th, 27th ... showdows

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to change the shadow type in MUI a I had to overwrite the theme and replace my shadow
I saw shadows.d.ts file and I didn't see any override method like others